# Adding rows to existing Java table result

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I try to choose a product from jComboBox (taking product name, price from mysql database), and then entering number of product. When I press to "Add Product" button, this code is :

```
Statement st = baglantiAc(); //Opening connection
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(
    "SELECT Product_Name, Product_Price, Product_Price*" +
    jTextField2.getText().toString() +
    " AS Total FROM products WHERE " +
    "Product_Name='" +
    jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");

myTableModel model = new myTableModel(res);
jTable1.setModel(model);
baglantiKapat(); //Closing connection
```

adding a product name, price, total price.

**Problem :**

When I want to add a product again and press **"Add Product"** button new result delete to original. I want to this like a list. Example :

```
    Product_name   Product_price  Total
        Apple           8          16
       Banana           3          15
     Strawberry         2          2
```

How can I manage that ?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of a query to update the rows in a table with different values.
I hope it helps you.

```
UPDATE northwind.employees 
SET 
    password = CASE EmployeeID
        WHEN 1 THEN 'admin1'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'admin2'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'admin3'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'admin4'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'admin5'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'admin6'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'admin7'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'admin8'
        WHEN 9 THEN 'admin9'
    END
WHERE
    EmployeeID IN (1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem is that you are inserting data right, but you can't display data correctly right?
if so have a separate method to get data from db and always call it when you do a insert